# Can a Function use another Function within the same Class?

Tags: python, function, inheritance, tkinter, global

I would like to reduce my code and thought to create one function collecting content from another Class and then refer my future Functions to "content_collector" to be able to access the variables (note_input, title_lable, ...).

First, as stated in the question, can Functions access variables in other Functions?

I also tried to make them a global variable but I receive a {SyntaxError: name 'note_input' is assigned to before global declaration}

Otherwise, I tried to create the variables outside of a Function but within the class, but there is, I assume, an inheritance issue because 'self' is not recognized.

```
class Functions:

    def content_collector(self):

        note_input = self.note_entry.get("1.0", "end-1c")
        title_label = self.title_entry.get()
        author_label = self.author_entry.get()
        year_label = self.year_entry.get()
        others_label = self.others_entry.get()

        global note_input, title_label, author_label, year_label, others_label


    def file_saveas(self):

       dic = {"title": title_label,
              "author": author_label,
              "year": year_label,
              "other": others_label,
              "note": note_input}

class EntryWidgets(Functions):

    def __init__(self, master):...
```

As always, thank you very much for your helpful answers!

Comment: add `self.` before `note_input`,`title_label`.....

Comment: No they cannot however if you define those variables as a class attribute any method within the function and even from outside the class can access them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [..] can Functions access variables in other Functions?

No. Variables are only accessible from inside their scope. In the case of your `content_collector`, your variables belong to the local scope of that function and can only be accessed from within that function. In addition to their scope, the variables also have a lifetime; they only exist while the function is executed. While `file_saveas` executes `content_collector` does not execute, hence the variables do not exist at this point.

As for your SyntaxError: as it says, you try to make your variables global *after* assigning values to them. You would need to move the `global` statement to the beginnig of your `content_collector` method. Even then, these names would only be known after `content_collector` has executed at least once (because only then, these names are made available outside of the local function scope by the `global` statement). Calling `file_saveas` before calling `content_collector` would result in a NameError.

Instead of making your variables global, you could either make them instance variables, e.g. in the `__init__` method or let `content_collector` return these values, e.g.:

```
class Functions:

    def content_collector(self):

        dic = {"note": self.note_entry.get("1.0", "end-1c"),
               "title": self.title_entry.get(),
               "author": self.author_entry.get(),
               "year": self.year_entry.get(),
               "other": self.others_entry.get()}
        return dic


    def file_saveas(self):

       dic = self.content_collector()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It works perfectly!
Just one question, why was my question downvoted? Is it too trivial or did I miss some standards?

Comment: @Alex_P Can't tell. I did not downvote it. Triviality does not qualify as a reason to downvote in my opinion. Possible reasons might include an apparent lack of effort (you could have looked up some documentation on `global`, at least after receiving the SyntaxError) or code that is not an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), meaning that it cannot be executed without alteration (we don't know what `self.note_entry` etc. are) and that it contains `EntryWidgets` that has no apparent relation to your question, other than being a subclass of `Functions`. ;)